# Сортировка вершин полигона

Tags: математика

Есть набор точек X Y Z. Как их можно отсортировать в нужном порядке, чтобы получилась область? Потом необходимо найти центр полученной области.

Comment: Что такое "нужный" порядок?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что три точки в любом порядке образуют треугольник.

Answer (score 4):

Задача в принципе неоднозначна - по крайней мере если многоугольник может быть невыпуклым: возможны разные варианты. Лень рисовать, представьте четыре вершины квадрата с номерами 1-4, и вершина 0 - в его центре. Варианты 0-1-2-3-4, 0-2-3-4-1 - вот уже пара неоднозначных вариантов.

Если известно, что вершины образуют выпуклый многоугольник - находим выпуклую оболочку, тут есть несколько алгоритмов - например, [сканирование Грехэма](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/convex_hull_graham).

Ну, а как найти центр - можно будет говорить после того, как вы поясните, что под этим понимаете...

**Update**

Пусть вершины A, B, C. Я предлагаю вам искать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а потом получать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я пока сам в процесс понимаю что нужно. Но уже ясно следующее, у нас есть точки с координатами x, y
A(3184.214, 5093,038)
B(3154.722, 5131.963)
C(3152.466, 5088.912)

Они образуют треугольник. И вот как найти значения выпуклостей от центра?

Comment: Что значит "значения выпуклостей от центра"? Что это за параметр? Что вы понимаете под центром треугольника? точку пересечения высот? Медиан? Биссектрис? Центр описанной окружности? Центр вписанной окружности?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0 Суть в том что необходимо найти значение удаления от Центроид треугольника. Т.е. мы строим треугольник, у нас 3 точки, ищем Центроид треугольника, и надо сместить координаты от Центроид треугольника до его вершин понимаете?

Comment: Когда мы это сделаем, мы уже не будем иметь таких глобальных и больших координат типо 3000+ или 5000+, у нас уже будет получается начало координат от Центроид треугольника и это будем считать 0.0.

Comment: Так, центроид - точка пересечения медиан. Найти его достаточно просто. Но если проблема просто в том, чтоб были не такие большие значения - то можно просто усреднить координаты точек :) Получаем какие-то (x0,y0). Дальше просто вычитаем их из значений (x,y) для вершин... Или я что-то опять не так понял?

Comment: да вы видимо правильно понял, усреднить так center.x - verticeX, center.y - verticeY?

Comment: См, дополненный ответ.

Comment: так же не могу понять в чем здесь еще осталась проблема. буду рад помочь з алгоритмом